# Efficient ETL Upsert in Redshift

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl, upsert

I'm having performance issues with ETLing update-able tables from our OLTP environment to Redshift. Our basic workflow is the typical OLTP->S3->Redshift data flow. Let's say I want to ETL a table like this

```
create table source_data (
id int primary key,
status varchar,
value decimal(10,4),
dateLastTouched datetime,
dateCreated datetime,
index datelasttouched_index (dateLastTouched));
```

to a similar table in Redshift. In preparation for the ETL, I made the sort key `dateLastTouched` and dist key `id`. We ETL any records with a dateLastTouched after the maximum dateLastTouched ETLd by the previous job.

This setup works very well for tables that don't have old records being updated (e.g. a record from last year changes its status), but when you add in that ability, I can't see anyway to ETL efficiently. The way we currently do it is:

1. Send all new or updated records to S3, using dateLastTouched.
2. COPY the data from S3 into a staging table.
3. Delete any records from the destination table that have the same primary key as the new data.
4. Insert all records from the staging table.

Given our setup with dateLastTouched as the sort key, step 3 is very very slow. Usually taking 1-2 minutes, and very clearly taking longer as time goes on. We can't change the sort key to the primary key because we need dateLastTouched for reporting queries that run rather frequently on the table. 
Some ideas we've considered:

1. Interleaved sort key of id and dateLastTouched. We tried this on another table and the performance gains weren't significant. Also the vacuum reindex times were terrible.
2. Don't delete, just insert and have periodic jobs materialize the "latest record per id" to another table. This isn't ideal because it practically doubles the space taken up by a large table, and updates aren't frequent.

Is there a better paradigm for efficient upserts from S3 to Redshift? Or do I just need to eat the ETL/materialized-view cost?

Comment: "..step 3 is very very slow. Usually taking 1-2 minutes.." - that doesn't actually sound particularly slow! What kind of time are you expecting for this step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to have 2 versions of the table, one sorted by `id` used for ETL and another sorted by `dateLastTouched` used for reporting. When ETL process is completed on the first one you just recreate the second (not using `order by` but just `truncate t2`, `insert into t2 select * from t1` and `vacuum reindex t2`)

Also, depending on the table size and configuration of your cluster it might be actually faster to reload the entire body of the table without taking care of upsert

Comment: Thanks for the idea!
One issue I can see with this is the time it takes to copy the data into the second table. I've done a deep copy on this table before, and it took about 45 minutes. For reference the table has ~500 million records and is about 19GB on disk.
Maybe I could load a "useful-for-reports" subset of the table to the second one,. Then again that would require using lastTouchedTime...

I'm not sure exactly what your second suggestion is, but reloading the entire table is out of the question, as we'd need to read 19+GB of S3 files.

Comment: @BatMasterson how exactly are you doing the deep copy so it's running for 45 minutes? and what's the config of your cluster? Also, if step 3 is taking 1-2 minutes on such a big table I think you're totally fine, that should be affordable

Comment: I am doing the usual deep copy process. Create new table, then insert into new table select * from old table. Fairly simple, but with larger data sets takes a while. I have a 600GB table that took 6 hours! My cluster is a single ds2.xlarge node, but I'm thinking of resizing when we can schedule the downtime.

The fact that step 3 is taking a minute isn't an issue yet, but I would expect that time to scale with the size of the table, which continues to grow. It's not practical to have an ETL run every 5 minutes when it take 7 minutes to execute, as an example.

Comment: is there a max difference between create and update time for your entities? if there is some time after which changes are highly unlikely (for example 90% entities are updated within a month from creation and 99% entities are updated within 6 months) you can update just that last portion of the table frequently and then run entire-table update less frequently to catch the rest 10% or 1%. You'll miss some updates for a few rows that were updated later but you'll save lots of resources if you skip the old blocks (since table is sorted by update time). How would that work for you?

Comment: Also if you have such a big table and want to perform ETL every 5 minutes it might make sense to move at least to two node setup to parallelize

Comment: I have played around with the idea of updating any older data less frequently, but cast it aside as requiring too much ETL complexity. Looking at it now, it may be preferable than the alternatives! Also, I've been putting off resizing the cluster due to the fact that it requires substantial 'read-only' time, but I guess sooner is better than later. Anyway thanks for the help! I guess there's no "one weird trick" to solve my performance issues.

Comment: I think old data update can be elegant. First, you can keep the files on S3 in a folder structure according to the frequency of your imports you can do this easily. You import the new files individually to staging table in the frequent job and then once a day import the entire content of the bucket, and in the ETL you run the same command, just add  something like `where dateLastTouched>current_date-interval '180 day'` in the frequent job vs. something that covers the entire period like 5 years or whatever.